# How to add another integrated dictionary to iOS9

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am learning Russian language and I was wondering if I could add a Russian-English dictionary to built-in dictionaries of iOS. I want to be able to look up Russian words in iBooks app without leaving the app.

Comment: There's no way yet for users to add integrated reference dictionaries to iOS as far as I know.  (It can be done for OS X, however.)

Answer (score 1):

I use Yandex.Translate by Yandex LLC
https://appsto.re/us/Vr50I.i

1. Get it from App Store
2. Set in the settings Russian
3. In Safari, Chrome, iBooks or somewhere else select word or phrase
4. Press Share, and choose Translate

   [image]

Sorry, but I can't add more images because I'm beginner

Answer (score -2):

- Tap on the word you want to define to select it and activate the popup.
- Tap on `Define` to call up the dictionary.
- Tap on `Manage` in the lower-left corner.
- If you find yourself in the word details screen, check for the `< Dictionary` selection on the upper-left to back to that screen.
- Tap the *iCloud* button beside any extra dictionaries you want to download.
- To delete a dictionary, swipe left and select `Delete`.

I've found this to be hit-and-miss.  Some dictionaries will show-up and some will not.  I don't know why but hopefully the dictionaries you want will be displayed.

Comment: But there is NO Russian - English dictionary provided by Apple so this will not be of any help.  You should delete this answer.

Comment: @TomGewecke I won't delete the answer because it answers the question in the title about how to add a dictionary in ios. While there is a Russian dictionary available there isn't a built-in one for translation. Someone could make one and this is how you add it.  I'm sure you down voted the answer for that reason.

Comment: Unfortunately It makes you look like you were unable to understand the actual question, which is how to add one which is not built in, and is of no help to the person who asked it.

Comment: I disagree.  In fact, it does make your comment completely incorrect because you stated "There's no way yet for users to add integrated reference dictionaries to iOS..." yet I just showed that it is possible.  Now the OP just has to find the specific translation dictionary he wants, or any kind of dictionary, actually, and I provided the instructions for adding it.

Comment: Only Apple can add such dictionaries.  There is no way for the user to "find" one anyplace other than inside iOS.  That is the whole point of this question.  Many people want to add new dictionaries to the built-in ones but it's not possible.  You don't seem to be aware of that fact.

Comment: it used to be possible in an older iOS version. I think I had done that in my good old iPhone 3G. So, I thought maybe there was a hack for it. Just to make it clear, my older iPhone was 'Jailbroken'!